# What is the best way to reduce a list with one value to the value? [a] -> a

Tags: javascript

In one project I generally work with a list that looks like this:

```
const listOfObjects = [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}, ...]
```

I filter the array for the selected object like this:

```
const getSelectedObject = list => list.filter(ob => ob.selected);
```

So my code looks like this:

```
const singleObjectList = getSelectedObject(listOfObjects);
```

`singleObjectList` supposed to be a list with a single element or an empty list of filter did not match any values.

I then try to get the 1st value of the list like this:

```
const fold = list => list.reduce((res, r) => r, null);
const ob = fold(singleObjectList)
```

The result of fold function can be either `null` or the last value in the list, in case the list has one value [a] it'll return a.

I feel a bit uncomfortable with this use of reduce. I wonder if there is a better/cleaner way to get a single value from a list.

**Update**

The solution is to use **[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**

I got great help, some folks have suggested to use:

```
list[0]
```

While technically it provides a solution, JavaScript provides useful functions to deal lists like filter, reduce and map. I wondered if I was missing something using `filter` and `reduce` combination for this task. And Indeed I was missing the `find` function.

Comment: maybe array.pop()?

Comment: pop() is not a pure function, I would rather create a reusable function that won't mutate the array which is passed to the function.

Comment: Surprised at why this question was downvoted

Comment: Same here @aquaraga

Comment: it looks like, the question wasn't clear, what you really want, as you stated in the comments. you could add that to the question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a result with either the first item or `null`, you could use a logical OR `||` to get a `null` value instead of an `undefined` for a not existence item.

```
var a = array[0] || null;
```

Or use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const listOfObjects = [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}],
      getSelected = a => a.selected,
      find = a => a.find(getSelected),
      result = find(listOfObjects);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Nina you previously suggested Array.prototype.find() which is exactly what I was looking for. Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Saw you fixed it! awesome :)

Comment: `||` will result in `null` if the value happens to be `0`, probably not correct.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, right, but the items look like objects.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with

```
list[0]
```

? Assuming it is certain to have 1 element.

Comment: Nothing is wrong per-se. It'll do that job. JavaScript provides useful functions to deal lists like filter, reduce and map. I would rather use the functional approach to solve this.

Comment: @SagiSergioNadir: I see the indexing operation as no less functional as those functions, just a different syntax, but still purely functional. Idempotent, pure.

Comment: In other words: you're talking nonsense.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath for me it's clearer to use an operation like reduce/find. For me the flow is cleaner and clearer that way. That's enough reason for me to look for an alternative for list[0]

Comment: @SagiSergioNadir: yes but if you're using arbitrary rules for your own amusement, at some point you're going closer to puzzling.stackexchange than to SO. But whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
list.reverse().find(item => item.selected)
```

Select **last** item from list that has `{ selected: true }`

Remove `reverse()` for the **first** item.

```js
const list = [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}]

const result = list.reverse().find(item => item.selected)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `list.find(item => item.selected)`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one step:

```
const listOfObjects = [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id: 2, selected: true}, ...]
const getSelected= list=>list.find(o=>o.selected);

let myObject=getSelected(listOfObjects);
```